# Getting my younger brother to eat healthier

Tags: diet, vegetables

I have a younger brother (I'm 17, he's 13) and for a while I had no idea just how unhealthy he eats.

Before addressing the question I should probably tell you more about his health condition. He's generally very healthy, he's pretty skinny but not in an excessive way. The problem with his alimentation is the fact he doesn't eat vegetables *at all*. I know what you're thinking, but he's very picky with food, his diet consists of meat, fruits during summer and grains. I've never actually talked with him about this, but I've recently asked him why he doesn't eat vegetables, and he repplied telling me that he wishes he could eat them, but when he starts eating them he feels the urge to puke them. He's never actually eaten a salad or a vegetable besides pickles or carrots and potatoes, nor did he ever eat mushrooms. Basically it's like this.

**He eats**:

- Fish (Ocasionally);
- Fruits;
- Meat;
- Grains;
- Foods from certain vegetables (Potatoes, carrots, pickles, etc)
- Sweets;

From his diet, vegetables are the #1 missing thing. He always says he feels the urge to vomit when he tries to eat vegetables, and I've actually seen him try to eat a salad last summer but then rejecting it, which makes me think he has will to do it, but something else could be the problem.

Knowing how healthy and beneficial veggies are, I want to help him add vegetables to his diet, but I don't know what I can do about it. How can I help him start eating vegetables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I help him start eating vegetables?

It's great that you're interested in your brother's health. Just keep in mind: you may not be able to actually help. This could be "just a phase he's going through", or it could be a longer-term neurosis. In the former case, it's no big deal; fortunately our young bodies are resilient and able to withstand even years of sub-optimal eating habits. In the latter case, medical and/or psychological intervention may be necessary. Or maybe it's something in between.

You could start with providing him with some educational material describing the health benefits of eating more vegetables and perhaps discussing the topic, at least get the ball rolling. Perhaps share some of the veggie recipes or dishes you particularly like, and encourage him to try them at least. Ensure him that you've never puked or become ill as a result of eating them! It may help, but it may not.

If it seems like it's a longer-term thing, you may need to consult with your parents and urge a doctor visit for further attention.